# Can you control how long content assist window stays open in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

It closes automatically after 2-3 seconds if there is no activity. Sometimes it is not enough time to read method/object documentation. 
I'm using Eclipse version: Photon Release (4.8.0) and working with java project.

Answer (score 0):

If you click in the java doc window it changes to a window which stays open until you press Esc or click outside the window.

It also has a tool bar at the bottom with some extra options.